# Can't get right link order out of Qt project file

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, qmake

I do have a test.cpp file that I know how to compile using g++ or Makefile

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -O3 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -ldrm
```

I am trying to make a Qt project file for compile like below:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -o3 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -ldrm 
SOURCES += test.cpp
```

but it always creates the wrong order for me:

```
g++ -O3 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -ldrm -std=c++11  -o test test.cpp
```

which results in **undefined reference to ....**
How should I solve this problem? The question is part of a big project with too many files that I can't write the proper Makefile for them manually. But I have traced the issue to a small sample and find the problem. So, I am looking for solutions to apply for project file rather that suggestions on using Makefile instead of Qt Project file.

Comment: Can you post a mcve?

Comment: Try `LIBS +=  -lGL -lGLU -lglut -ldrm` instead of putting them in `QMAKE_LFLAGS`.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using qmake or gnu make ?

Comment: @RustyX thanks it worked. You may write your comments as answer so that I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: You should also look into refactoring your code to break it into a couple of modules, so that you can specify which modules require specific libs regardless of order and which module requires another module to already be linked with the right libraries.  Odds are that this refactoring will also speed up your builds.